# Decal shader not working on Device

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, mobile, shader

I'm really novice and this is first time I wrote a shader for unity mobile game.
Here is the shader, working well on Editor but not on my android device :

```
                Shader "Decal" {
            Properties {
             _Skin("Skin (RGB)", 2D) = "white" {}
             _Dirt("Dirt (RGBA)", 2D) = "black" {}
             _Outfit("Outfit (RGBA)", 2D) = "black" {}
             _Painting("Painting (RGBA)", 2D) = "black" {}
             _Cheek("Cheek (RGBA)", 2D) = "black" {}
             _LipStick("LipStick (RGBA)", 2D) = "black" {}
             _Eye("Eye (RGBA)", 2D) = "black" {}
             _EyeLid("EyeLid (RGBA)", 2D) = "black" {}
             _ShadowHat("ShadowHat (RGBA)", 2D) = "black" {}
            }
            SubShader {
            Tags { "RenderType"="Opaque" }
            LOD 150

            CGPROGRAM
            #pragma surface surf Lambert noforwardadd

            sampler2D _Skin;
            sampler2D _Dirt;
            sampler2D _Outfit;
            sampler2D _Painting;
            sampler2D _Cheek;
            sampler2D _LipStick;
            sampler2D _Eye;
            sampler2D _EyeLid;
            sampler2D _ShadowHat;

            struct Input {
            float2 uv_Skin;
            };

            void surf (Input IN, inout SurfaceOutput o) {
            fixed4 c = tex2D(_Skin, IN.uv_Skin);
            fixed4 dirt = tex2D(_Dirt, IN.uv_Skin);
            fixed4 outfit = tex2D(_Outfit, IN.uv_Skin);
            fixed4 painting = tex2D(_Painting, IN.uv_Skin);
            fixed4 cheek = tex2D(_Cheek, IN.uv_Skin);
            fixed4 lipstick = tex2D(_LipStick, IN.uv_Skin);
            fixed4 eye = tex2D(_Eye, IN.uv_Skin);
            fixed4 eyelid = tex2D(_EyeLid, IN.uv_Skin);
            fixed4 shadowHat = tex2D(_ShadowHat, IN.uv_Skin);

            c.rgb = lerp (c.rgb, dirt.rgb, dirt.a);
            c.rgb = lerp (c.rgb, outfit.rgb, outfit.a);
            c.rgb = lerp (c.rgb, painting.rgb, painting.a);
            c.rgb = lerp (c.rgb, cheek.rgb, cheek.a);
            c.rgb = lerp (c.rgb, lipstick.rgb, lipstick.a);
            c.rgb = lerp (c.rgb, eye.rgb, eye.a);
            c.rgb = lerp (c.rgb, eyelid.rgb, eyelid.a);
            c.rgb = lerp (c.rgb, shadowHat.rgb, shadowHat.a);

            o.Albedo = c.rgb;
            o.Alpha = c.a;
            }
            ENDCG
            }

            Fallback "Mobile/VertexLit"
            }
```

So any help would be very welcome :),and also one thing to clarify, I'm not sure the performance of this shader is good enough for mobile ?

Thanks you very much !

Comment: What's the Graphics API your device supports?

Comment: On my Unity's playerSettings, the graphic API is set to OpenGLES2

Answer (score 1):

According to this [Unity Manual](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/GraphicsEmulation.html), OpenGL ES 2.0 only supports the maximum of 8 textures in a single shader.
Also, if you go to the **Edit > Graphics Emulation** menu and choose **OpenGL ES 2.0**, you can see the shader warnings for it.

> I'm not sure the performance of this shader is good enough for mobile ?

You're using too many **sampler2D's** in a single shader. Also you should avoid expensive math functions in shader code. Your shader is expensive for mobile.

You can read more about mobile optimization [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/MobileOptimisation.html) and [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/SL-ShaderPerformance.html).

Comment: Oh ok That 's the reason the shader is not working on device !
Thanks, and thanks for the links !

Answer (score 0):

So now I feel I'm doing it the wrong way. This shader is done for a character customisation and my shader skills are near to 0 so I will give up for this solution.

Finally I think it's better to merge needed texture at runtime and apply the result to a mobile shader.